# Add action to action bar panel

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I want to add an action to the action bar, but it appears in my action bar as a drop down list.
How can I add button to the action bar?
My code is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="Add"
      showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>

  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Are you pointing to current xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `android.app.Activity` simply change `showAsAction="always"` to `"android:showAsAction="always"`.

If you are using `android.support.v7.app.Activity` change the code as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Are you using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` or `android.app.Activity`?

Comment: I use  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Comment: In case of `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` you will have to place this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` attribute in the `menu` parent element and then instead of `android:showAsAction="always"` write `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Always remember, this `app:` and `android:` business is due to the support APIs that android has. `app:` is for `support.v7` and `android:` is for normal `Activity`. Similarly in your code, to get `ActionBar`, call `getSupportActionBar()` if you are using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and `getActionBar()` if you are using `android.app.Activity`

Comment: Whot is this mean?xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: It defines the name space of `android` and `app`. The namespace of `app` is given separately to provide support for `ActionBar` for devices <API 11 and >API 7

Comment: but in your answer i use android: and app?

Comment: Yes because you are using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` which is a support library by android and for support you have to define this `app` namespace too using `xmlns:app=....`

Answer (score -1):

You just simply add the one more item into menu and inflate that menu into your activity ....
        like below you will add your button and access that button into your activity...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
            showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_button_cancel"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    </menu>
```

Inflating the menu like below.....

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Accessing method in action bar item is....

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:  
                          //logic       
            return true;
                case R.id.action_bar_button_cancel:
                          //logic       
                       return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

that's if you have any doubt comment

Comment: But why i can not add only one button?

Comment: i have added one more item, but it does not helped me

Comment: No, this does not help me

Comment: It will not do any thing it will give the only effect while you touching the item that's all