# app:showAsAction ifRoom is not working on appcompat action bar

Tags: android

I have an action bar with the following menu items;

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.blah.blah.app.ClientActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="5"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_waiter"
        android:title="@string/action_waiter"
        android:orderInCategory="6"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_cleantable"
        android:title="@string/action_cleantable"
        android:orderInCategory="7"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_suggest"
        android:title="@string/action_suggest"
        android:orderInCategory="8"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_waiterlogin"
        android:title="@string/action_waiterlogin"
        android:orderInCategory="9"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

The problem is my search button doesn't show on action bar but the text is showed in overflow. There's plenty of room in my action bar

I'm using `"@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I answered a question similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22780579/2801779

Comment: @HipHopDroid the `app` namespace is already there. So, it is not actually the same problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please Try to use 
 `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` instead of  `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

Comment: Omg it really worked. I thought in AppCompat, we need to use `app:showAsAction`. Thanks mate

Comment: Error from Android Studio. When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the showAsAction in the app: namespace, not the android: namespace.

Comment: Is this really still the same problem 3 years later?

Comment: No, things are changed now

Comment: This generates error with AppCompat lib. He must have a namespace declaration xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto on the menu parent tag to apply app namespace prefix

Comment: `android:showAsAction` will give you a lint error and if you use CI/CD, your build will fail. The only way to do this without errors is following the solution by Mario Eraso below.

Comment: Unexpected namespace URI bound to the "android" prefix, was http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto, expected http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to add a few lines to onCreateOptionsMenu.

Android Studio didn't let me use android:showAsAction="ifRoom" while using appCompat.

app:showAsAction="ifRoom" wasn't working and I removed it without problems.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater  inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: This is the only way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else gets into the same problem - I could not get the button to show up until I overrode the onCreateOptionsMenu function and Inflated the menu (I am using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1 version)

Here is the code snippet:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ToolBar (that is in ActivityBar) strives not to exceed some amount of visible elements. And that limit is lower than ToolBar can contain indeed. The limit is set in *android.support.v7.view.ActionBarPolicy* class:

```
`/**
     * Returns the maximum number of action buttons that should be permitted within an action
     * bar/action mode. This will be used to determine how many showAsAction="ifRoom" items can fit.
     * "always" items can override this.
     */
    public int getMaxActionButtons() {
        final Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        final int widthDp = ConfigurationHelper.getScreenWidthDp(res);
        final int heightDp = ConfigurationHelper.getScreenHeightDp(res);
        final int smallest = ConfigurationHelper.getSmallestScreenWidthDp(res);
```

if (smallest > 600 || widthDp > 600 || (widthDp > 960 && heightDp > 720)
            || (widthDp > 720 && heightDp > 960)) {
        // For values-w600dp, values-sw600dp and values-xlarge.
        return 5;
    } else if (widthDp >= 500 || (widthDp > 640 && heightDp > 480)
            || (widthDp > 480 && heightDp > 640)) {
        // For values-w500dp and values-large.
        return 4;
    } else if (widthDp >= 360) {
        // For values-w360dp.
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}`

As you can see the limit is between 2 and 5, and it depends on the screen width. So if you want to exceed the limit, you should use *showAsAction="always"* or create your own view for ActionBar .

Answer (score 0):

You must have a namespace for the app declaration to work

```
<menu ......
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

for the app namespace prefix to work in your action item.

Answer (score 0):

`app:showAsAction` is an `AppCompatActivity` attribute. You could use `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` instead of `android.view.MenuInflater`. Code sample could be as below

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Change to

```
   android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```